# Find new messages added to an imap mailbox since I last checked with python imaplib2?

Tags: python, imap, python-idle, imaplib

I am trying to write a program that monitors an IMAP mailbox and automatically copies every new incoming message into an "Archive" folder. I'm using imaplib2 which implements the IDLE command. Here's my basic program:

```
M = imaplib2.IMAP4("mail.me.com")
M.login(username,password)
lst = M.list()
assert lst[0]=='OK'
for mbx in lst[1]:
    print "Mailboxes:",mbx

def process(m):
    print "m=",m
    res = M.recent()
    print res


M.select('INBOX')
M.examine(mailbox='INBOX',callback=process)
while True:
    print "Calling idle..."
    M.idle()
    print "back from idle"
M.close()
M.logout()
```

It prints the mailboxes properly and runs process() when the first change happens to the mailbox. But the response from recent() doesn't make sense to me, and after the first message I never get any other notifications.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See example and references in [python-imap-idle-with-imaplib2](https://web.archive.org/web/20100430182530/https://blog.hokkertjes.nl/2009/03/11/python-imap-idle-with-imaplib2) (Wayback Machine snapshot).
The module involves threading, you should pay attention to event synchronization.

The example suggests synchronizing with events, and leaves mail processing to the reader:

```
# The method that gets called when a new email arrives. 
# Replace it with something better.
def dosync(self):
    print "Got an event!"
```

Taking a hint from the question, *"something better"* can be:

```
# Replaced with something better.
def dosync(self):
    print "Got an event!"
    res = self.M.recent()
    print res
```

Comment: Thanks. But the code only alerts each time a message is returned; how do I get the UID of the messsage so that I can do something with it?

Comment: Thanks. I'm putting together a app now!

Answer (score 2):

I am finding that recent() is a bit vague (this is an IMAP vagueness, not imaplib2).  Seems better to keep a list of message numbers before and after idle, and the difference is new messages.

Then use fetch(messages,"UID") to get the message uid.

Comment: Yeah. recent() ended up not working for me. I've also had problems with imaplib2() - it just freezes up after running for a few hours. Not sure how to proceed...

Do you have code that works?