# Gmail messages, unable to split message Ids

Tags: python, split, gmail-imap

I am reading gmail messages ([using the code from accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210737/get-only-new-emails-imaplib-and-python))

```
(retcode, messages) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
if retcode == 'OK':
    for num in messages[0].split(' '): # messages[0] is b'6' in my case.
```

It's throwing, "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'".
But I can see clearly its a byte object `b'6'`

Tried same on python shell as well and getting same error there as well. Not sure whats wrong here.

```
>>> b'6'.split(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

When it gives you the `TypeError`, it is **not** referring to the `b'6'`... it is rather referring to the `' '` in `.split()` -- it is trying to split a bytes object with a string. To fix this, simply change the line to:

```
(retcode, messages) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
if retcode == 'OK':
    for num in messages[0].split(b' '): # messages[0] is b'6' in my case.
```

Or, in the case of the python shell

```
>>> b'6'.split(b' ')
[b'6']
```